# Stopping lvim search task

Tags: vim

I accidentally launched [lvim search](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_in_files_within_Vim) among a very large amount of binary files. How can I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in Linux terminal Vim, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> aborts the search after the current file has been processed with a `E480: No match` error.